# SQL Query to Calculate two Amounts on the same row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

probably a very simple answer but i'm new to T-SQL so could do with some help!

I need a 3rd column that works out TotInc - (minus) TotEx to give me a TotalDisposableIncome

Here is my SQL:

--This gives me the Total Income and Total Expenditure on the same row

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN Type = '1' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as TotalInc,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Type = '2' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as TotEx
    FROM ClaimFinancials
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a Common Table Expression (CTE):

```
WITH T1 AS
(
    SELECT
        SUM(CASE WHEN Type = '1' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as TotalInc,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Type = '2' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as TotEx
    FROM ClaimFinancials
)
SELECT TotalInc, TotEx, TotalInc - TotEx AS TotalDisposableIncome
FROM T1
```

Or an ordinary subquery:

```
SELECT TotalInc, TotEx, TotalInc - TotEx AS TotalDisposableIncome
FROM
(
    SELECT
        SUM(CASE WHEN Type = '1' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as TotalInc,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Type = '2' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as TotEx
    FROM ClaimFinancials
) T1
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't reference your column aliases elsewhere in your SELECT clause.  Here is one alternative.

```
SELECT TotalInc, TotEx, TotInc - TotEx as TotalDisposable
FROM (
    SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN Type = '1' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as TotalInc,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Type = '2' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as TotEx
    FROM ClaimFinancials
    ) AS Total
```

Comment: That does the trick as well (after I changed TotInc to TotalInc) Thank you also

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN Type = '1' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as TotalInc, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN Type = '2' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as TotEx,
  SUM(CASE 
    WHEN Type = '1' THEN Amount 
    WHEN Type = '2' Then -Amount 
    ELSE 0
  END) AS TotalDisposableIncome
FROM ClaimFinancials
```

Answer (score 0):

There's more than one way to do it.

```
WITH T1 AS 
( 
  SELECT 
    Type,    
    SUM(Amount as Total 
  FROM ClaimFinancials 
) 
SELECT 
  Inc.Total as TotalInc, 
  Ex.Total as TotEx, 
  Inc.Total - Ex.Total AS TotalDisposableIncome 
FROM T1 Inc, T2 Ex
where T1.Type = 1 and T2.Type = 2
```